# Needs audio progress bar like soundcloud react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, progress-bar, audio-player

I needs progress bar like soundcloud (Pointer fixed in center) [Like This](https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-098aafb8a1fc.gif)

I tried with [React Native Slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slider) but unable fixed in center

```
function TrackProgres() {  
  const bufferedPosition = 0
  const duration = 600

  return (    
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
      <ImageBackground source={require('../../../../assets/images/sound.png')} style={{width:550, height: 40,zIndex:-1,left: 50,marginRight: -50 }} imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'repeat'}}>
        <Slider 
          style={{width: 550}}
          value={bufferedPosition}
          maximumValue={duration}
          minimumTrackTintColor="#292b2c"
          maximumTrackTintColor="#292b2c"
          thumbStyle={styles.thumb}
          trackStyle={styles.track}
          onValueChange={(value) => seekTo(value)}
            /> 
    </ImageBackground> 
    </ScrollView>
   )
```

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: Yes @tudor.gergely I added code 
Please check

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for isn't a slider - it's just a conditional rendering on a background position.  Think of it like this:

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

return (
    <View
        style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            height: 30,
            width,
            top: 0,
            left: (width / 2) - (width * percentComplete),
            backgroundColor: '#F00',
        }}
    >
        <View
            style={{
                 position: 'absolute',
                 backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                 top: 0,
                     left: (width / 2) - 1,
                 width: 2,
                 height: 30,
            }}
        />
    </View>
);
```

If you render these with `percentComplete` as a value between 0 and 1, the background View will be offset properly.

At 0% complete, the View will start at `left: width / 2`, or the center of the screen.  As `percentComplete` increases, that offset will decrease, and go beyond the left edge of the screen after 50% complete.  At 100%, the right edge of the background View will be at the midpoint of the screen.

The foreground View remains in the center.

Comment: Please check https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-098aafb8a1fc.gif first 
OR try soundcloud app